# How can I use an SVM to seperate two classes in a 2D map?

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, svm, boundary

I have 2d-numpy array of points defining a map with obstacles [Image of the 2D Map of which I am trying to create an SVM with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71R9w.png). The values of this 2d-array are either 0 for open space (grey) or 1,-1 for obstacles (black/white). The formatting of the map is shown below:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1. ...  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  1.]
 ...
 [ 1.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1. -1. ...  1.  1.  1.]]
```

My goal is to use a Support Vector Machine (SVM) to create a line/decision boundary between the obstacles. Since the obstacles are two separate classes, it should be possible to generate an SVM separating them. The ideal SVM boundary would look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4M85.png).

What I am unsure of us how to transform my data to be in the format shown in the [sklearn SVM example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html). I need to be able to specify the features, `X` and the target, `y`, so I can train the SVM by calling something like `svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C).fit(X, y)` as shown in the example.

In summary: how to convert my map (a 2-d array of either `-1, 1, 0`) into a set of features and targets?

Comment: SVM is a linear classifier so the optimal boundary would certainly not look like in your example but be a straight line. The format you need to bring your data in is labeled feature vectors, which are the coordinates. So X would be a list of points (locations in your 2D map) and y would be the corresponding list of labels -1, 1, ie. the values you find at the specific coordinate in your 2D map. The coordinates of non-labeled points you would simply not provide.